# DOM pass argument to javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, dom, arguments

I need to found other way how to use javascript function.

```
var b = ce("input"); // Here I create element.
b.setAttribute("name", "g4");
b.value = "Centimetrais(pvz:187.5)";
b.onfocus = function() { remv(this); };
b.onchange = function() { abs(this); };
b.onkeypress = function() { on(event); }; // I need to change this place becose then I pass "event" argument function doesn't work.
ac(1, "", b); // Here I appendChild element in form.
```

**Here is the function:**

```
function on(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt|| window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /^[0-9.,]+$/;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

In IE and chrome it work but in mozilla doesn't. Any alternative how to fix it for firefox?

Also at this path other function working in mozilla if pass other argument like "car","dog",this. For example:

```
firstFunction();
function firstFunction() {
var b = ce("input"); // Here I create element.
b.onkeypress = function() { on("hi!"); };
ac(1, "", b); // Here I appendChild element in form.
}
function on(evt) {
  alert(evt);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `b.onkeypress = function(event) { on(event); };`?

Comment: No I didn't I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is that you're not accepting the event argument in the main handler. E.g., in your first example:

```
b.onkeypress = function() { on(event); };
```

it should be

```
b.onkeypress = function(e) { on(e || window.event); };
// Changes here --------^ and --^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're doing that in `on`, but in `on`, it's already too late, you've lost the argument provided to the `onXYZ` function.

The reason your code works in Chrome and IE is that IE uses a global `event` object instead of (or in modern versions, in addition to) the one it actually passes into the handler, and Chrome replicates that behavior for maximum compatibility with websites that expect that. Firefox does not.